# How to implement inverted index from string list to dictionary using dict comprehension and auto-incremental id?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compression, inverted-index

Can you suggest me a dictionary comprehension to iterate over list of items and hash them in dictionary with value equal to auto-incremented integer id? Or some method to get value from generator or other list?

Is there possible something like this:

```
iverted_index_dict = {key: (auto_increment_here) in object_list }
```

my current sollution:

```
object_list = ["trip", "thre", "tree", "noya", "goya", "voya"]


invid1 = {object_list[i]: i+1 for i in xrange(0,len(object_list))}
print invid1

invid2 = {}
i=0
for item in object_list:
    i += 1
    invid2[item] = i

print invid2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> {k:v for v, k in enumerate(object_list, 1)}
{'goya': 5, 'noya': 4, 'thre': 2, 'tree': 3, 'trip': 1, 'voya': 6}
```